# Auto node redirct depending on a cck field's content

Tags: 6, redirection

When a visitor goes node/123, I need them to be redirected to the url that is specified in that node's cck field.  I know there are plenty of modules that do redirects, but I need this specific type of automation.  What would be the best way to go abut this?

Answer (score 3):

There is multiple way of doing this. Probably the best one is create a custom module and

Using hook_menu_alter(), alter the page callback for node/%node. In your page callback, check the type of the node to invoke node_page_view on the node or redirect to the referenced node.

```
MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'MODULE_node_page_view';
}

MODULE_node_page_view($node) {
  if ($node->type == MODULE_NODE_TYPE) {
    //if fixed_x is a node nid
    $reference = $node->field_x;
    drupal_goto('node/'. $referenced_node->nid);
    //if fixed_x is a path
    drupal_goto($node->field_x);
    //etc
  }
  else {
    return node_page_view($node);
  }
}
```